# Shopping Behavior Analysis shows wrong data in Google Analytics in Initiate checkout

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, bigcommerce, enhanced-ecommerce

It happens that the shopping behavior funnel is showing a strange behavior in Initiate checkout, the number of events launched is higher compared to those added to the cart and that could not be possible. I would like you to help me with this please.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGgdm.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your e-comm settings: when event "check out" fires.

Comment: Hi zborovskaya, If the events that are being launched normally were reviewed. each event has already been tested. But the fault is not found.

Answer (score 0):

The issue strictly correlates with the way of how and where you're triggering the checkout started event. It looks like the event is triggered multiple times.

I had similar issues and in my case it was caused by incorrectly configured Google Tag Manager trigger which was firing at checkout and also on the order confirmation page.